404 Error Using Frankfurter API & Python Virtual Environment
I am making a currency converter script in Python in Visual Studio Code and I'm using the frankfurter API, it used to work fine about a few days ago until now where everytime I try to fetch the API I get the 404 error:
>     response = requests.get(f"https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount={amount}&from={CF}&to={CT}")
>     print("API Response:", response.json())
>     print(response.status_code)

Output:
API Response: {'message': 'not found'}
404
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OMEN\Visual Studio\RTCurrencyConverter\Converter.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(f"{amount} {CF} is {response.json()['rates'][CT]} {CT}")
KeyError: 'rates'

Virtual environments for me have been very inconsistent in general and I kept trying to remove and recreate environments hoping that would fix something but to no avail.

Hello, judging by the output, it could be an issue with the API. You can switch to a different virtual environment to try it out, or update the requests library. If you're having an issue with the API, you can check to see if the API documentation has been changed or try to change the new currency conversion API. See if that solves the problem.

I've tried the api and it works as expected also it does not seem like a problem with the requests from Python3. Below i show some of the cases which might be the problem.
Below is a correct usage with a correct response.
https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount=2&from=USD&to=GBP

{"amount":2.0,"base":"USD","date":"2024-07-30","rates":{"GBP":1.5569}}

This one is not a correct usage. See the from param instead of USD i wrote UST got us 404 with the same response you got:
https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount=2&from=UST&to=GBP

404 {"message":"not found"}

Or it might be if your CF or CT params are None like below example.
I sent empty to param:
https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount=2&from=USD&to=
404 {"message":"not found"}

Log your params before sending the request and take a look like below code:
request_url = f"https://api.frankfurter.app/latest?amount={amount}&from={CF}&to={CT}"
print(f"Trying the request \n {request_url}")
response = requests.get(request_url)
print("API Response:", response.json())
print(response.status_code)


I just realised that the error was due to me using a currency not available in the API, appears as though this API is pretty limited as I tried using AED as the currency and got the 404 error but when I used the USD or GBP as you did it worked fine. Are you aware of another real time currency exchange rates API that contains more/all exchange rates?

You can take a look at this .  It's not entirely free, but it offers 1.5K API requests per month with support for 161 currencies. If you found my answer helpful, I would appreciate an upvote or accepting the answer. Thank you!
